# Spec failing after upgrade to Rails 5 rc1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capybara, ruby-on-rails-5

I have very simple spec that looks like this:

```
scenario 'show error message' do
  expect(page).to have_text 'Invalid email or password.'
end
```

After upgrading to Rails 5 rc1 it fails:

```
  1) Sign in when email and password are invalid show error message
     Failure/Error: expect(page).to have_text 'Invalid email or password.'
       expected to find text "Invalid email or password." in "× Invalid Email or password. Sign in Please fill the form to sign in to your account * Email * Password Remember me (if this is a private computer) Forgot password? Copyright @ 2016"
```

Test are passing on Rails 5 beta3.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Email is now capitalized. Change it in the spec (or, better yet, use a more tolerant test so this doesn't happen again).

Comment: OMG. Thanks. But why in the past spec was passing?

Comment: I'd guess they changed it? That's usually what happens with, like, 'new versions' and stuff. The major releases often have deep breaking changes like this.